# Run job in GKE using a java client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have seen that it is possible to use the amazon aws java sdk to run jobs in an ECS cluster, this is done by using the class

com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECS;

and using the method

runTask()

This is shown here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ecs/AmazonECS.html

Now I would like to do the same but using Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), that is, I want to be able to connect to the cluster from a java application to launch a Job inside the cluster. I have been taking a look at the class

ClusterManagerClient

It has a method called

getCluster()

as shown here

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-container/latest/com/google/cloud/container/v1/ClusterManagerClient.html

However the Cluster object does not have any methods to run Jobs in the cluster

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-container/latest/com/google/container/v1/Cluster.html

I was wondering if google has any library similar to AWS to do this.

Comment: So, the two services are similar but not quite. GKE is a Managed Kubernetes service more similar to EKS. I don't know AWS well but think ECS is more similar to Cloud Run. To answer your question, you can use that Java method to get the Kubernetes cluster's credentials. You must then use a Kubernetes library to create a Config object that the Kubernetes client can then use to create a Kubernetes Job. The Container (Kubernetes) service is a meta service for connecting to clusters, interacting with clusters is done via `kubectl` or libraries.

Comment: Have a look at Cloud Run's new [Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) as this may (!?) be a closer analog to what you want on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GKE, like EKS, you are on Kubernetes environment. You can run a pod job if you want to run a Job!

In serverless world, you have Cloud Run Jobs, as mentioned by DazWilkin in the comments, but you have a timeout limited to 1H (if your job take longer prefer a PodJob, on GKE, or GKE Autopilot if y ou don't want to worry about cluster admin)

You can also have a look to the brand new [Batch service](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started) on Google Cloud that perform something similar to AWS: Spawn a VM (Compute Engine) and run your container (or your code) on it. Destroy it at the end.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/JobExample.java